How can I get a monochrome version of an image?
Is there a possibility to transform a bitmap into a monochrome bitmap image using Skia?
I am new to the Delphi programming language and Skia framework, but I understand that this is somehow possible in Skia. Using the Skia APIs, you can draw anything using color filter, so, you can change the color, remove the saturation (to apply grayscale), and much more
I have a PNG image on my PC and want to basically get a monochrome version of it so that I can print it.

I have no idea of Skia but if you can get it to an actual bitmap you could use Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.Monochrome property

@complete_stranger oh. That might be what I am looking for. Thank you. I will look now

@complete_stranger Monochrome means one colour. A VCL TBitmap is a loose wrapper around the Windows GDI HBITMAP. There monochrome means 1 bit per pixel. So no this is categorically not remotely what is needed for greyscale. Also, it's not Skia.
